# Android OpenGL20 error on command glUniformMatrix4fv

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I'm getting an error on the following command:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    // *******************************************************************
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    // *******************************************************************
    Utils.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv muMVPMatrixHandle");

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Utils.checkGlError("glClear GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT");

    GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW);
    Utils.checkGlError("glFrontFace GL_CW");

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    Utils.checkGlError("glUseProgram mProgram");

    drawFrame();
}
```

And I can't figure out the problem! this part of the code is taken from an example on the android dev guide...
When I debug the code, i can see that muMVPMatrixHandle is not -1, it is a valid value, also mMVPMatrix seems valid.
Error code is 1282 if it helps...

Comment: This is mainly a guess, but I think you should move glUseProgram(mProgram) before assigning values into shaders.

Comment: Solved the problem by moving the glUseProgram command above the glUniformMatrix4fv command.
EDIT: harism, just saw your comment now after solving the problem. But that did do the trick so get an upvote :)